# How to wrap .header.content?

Tags: magento2, blocks, xml, html

I need to wrap *.header.content* in a . How can I do that using *default.xml* file?

I think using something like that:

```
        <referenceBlock name="header-wrapper">
            <container htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header-main-wrapper">
                <block name="??? />
            </container>
        </referenceBlock>
```

I cannot find the block name... how can I find it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did in this way:

```
<referenceBlock name="header.container">
    <container name="header-main-wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header-main-wrapper" />
</referenceBlock>

<move element="header-wrapper" destination="header-main-wrapper" before="-" />
```